# How can I setup an SSL environment to test C# remoting?

Tags: c#, ssl, https, remoting

Our customer has asked that our application be able to communicate through HTTPS.  The application itself is a C#.NET application, a client/server/database sort of application.  My understanding from my programmer is that this is an additional layer of unnecessary encryption, but because our customer has asked for it we're going to try to provide it anyway.

What I'm looking for is a way to setup an SSL environment that does not require me to install a webserver.  Although we could recompile our server into a DLL that could allow us to be hosted through IIS, the idea doesn't exactly thrill me (we're not wanting our customer to have to implement IIS in addition to our solution).

In any case, the idea is to provide an SSL tunnel over port 443 that our C#.NET remoting packets (they're http packets at the moment) may pass through.

Does anybody have any suggestions which may prove helpful in this regard?  Do we need to add any additional handling to the communication process to allow this?  (My gut says no, but I'm not the programmer.)

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article on MSDN:

[.NET Remoting: Writing an Asymmetric Encryption Channel Sink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300447.aspx)

First header is 'Support For HTTPS'